# Why isn't my re.sub finding all instances using my regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm using Python 3.10 on Windows 10 and trying the search below:

```
re.sub(r'(.*[A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'JohnnyB Cool & JoeCool')
'JohnnyB Cool & Joe Cool'
```

If I use just "JohnnyB Cool", the "B" gets a space before it.

```
re.sub(r'(.*[A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'JohnnyB Cool')
'Johnny B Cool'
```

Why isn't the "JohnnyB" substituted in the first search?  I've also tried:

```
re.sub(r'(.*)([A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z])', r'\1 \2 \3', 'JohnnyB Cool & JoeCool')
'JohnnyB Cool &  Joe Cool'
```

To be clear, I want the final answer to be, `Johnny B Cool & Joe Cool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this python code:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = 'JohnnyB Cool & JoeCool'
>>> print (re.sub(r'\B[A-Z]', r' \g<0>', s))
Johnny B Cool & Joe Cool
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BA28KF/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\B` matches where `\b` doesn't i.e. adjacent to another word character
- `[A-Z]` matches an uppercase letter

Comment: Done.  And thank you for the demo page too.  That's cool!